# Why does Google obscure HTML/CSS classes on Google+?

Tags: google-plus

The attachment is a screenshot of Chrome Developer Tools when looking at Google+ HTML. Note the ~random classnames:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The source for unreadable identifiers can be:

- minification
- obfuscation
- random Id generation

Google Plus is probably implemented as a GWT (or similar framework) application with minified resources (javascript and css files) and automatically generated identifiers. Minification is also widely used as a tool for obfuscating the code so the unreadability is partly intentional too.

Comment: so why intentionally obfuscate it?

Comment: To make it harder to extract the business logic.

Comment: the difference between minified and obfuscated is, that the first is to compress the content (and load faster) while the other is to hide stuff or make it harder to view. In the case of GWT, the IDs are generated on the fly and therefore look terrible

Answer (score 0):

Obfuscation can be used to reduce code size, as well as reduce code readability for an "unauthorized" user to make it harder to reverse-engineer a product/program or steal ideas. Someone asked a pretty similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871566/why-do-you-obfuscate-your-code), that should answer any more questions that you have.