# how do i hide my source files in the website to be not accessible by users

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, browser

[click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXcnD.png)I have a Website some xyz.com, I have restricted users to access the folders in it.
it's written on Mean.

when user tries to access it using xyz.com/users/component he is not able to access it where as when he give xyz.com/users/component/component.controller.js . he is able to access the file how do I restrict it?

How can I hide my entire project to be visible when user click inspect element, its okay for me to view HTML but then when user clicks source he can see all of my controllers how do I restrict that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not fundamentally possible. If you have sensitive information like client IDs or secrets, you can use [.env files to store these on your server](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-keep-your-secret-keys-safe-secure-8b1a7877d69c) or [obfuscate your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871566/why-do-you-obfuscate-your-code) to make it less readable for human eyes.

As well, you can disable opening the context menu with Javascript, but this doesn't do much but give a false sense of security.

`document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());`

It'd be good to specify exactly what you're trying to protect so people can recommend best practices for you.

Comment: I was trying to hide controller which have some sensible information vulnerable to hack my website

Comment: Your users will see the rendered view, not your controllers.

Comment: If you still want some added security when working with repos, though, see the articles I linked on using envs to store your environment variables so you can keep them isolated to one secure file.

Comment: Nope, it was all my controllers in the souce in inspect

Comment: I don't believe that should be.. could you get a screenshot of an example? When you say Controllers, you mean MVC controllers, correct?

Comment: I have added image please check @CodeSpent I am using meanjs.org boiler plate, please tell me how do I hide my controllers

Comment: One of the user of my application hacked it using the controllers